Getting Wordpress to work with query parameters from the url instead of redirecting to error page
I'm trying to make a search page for a journal's website, where you can search with keywords and with wordpress categories (single or multi-select), and the end result displays at the same url with the parameters at the end.
Ideally:

mywebsite.com/search/ would display the empty search bar with some default posts
the search form has checkboxes for which of the categories the user wants to filter by (multiselect)
clicking search takes you to eg. mywebsite.com/search?s=searchtext&?category=somecategory, which is the exact same page except that the default posts are replaced by ones matching the query

I've tried a few free plugins and they do not do what I need. My organisation (small student group) can't afford most paid ones, and I'm trying to learn anyways. I'm currently editing on a child theme based on 2024.
This is the search form I made (custom html):
<form method="get" action="https://mywebsite.com/search" class="wp-block-search__button-outside wp-block-search__icon-button">

    <div class="search-page-searchbox" style="display: flex">
        <input class="wp-block-search__input has-heading-font-family" id="wp-block-search__input-2" placeholder="" value="" name="s" required="" style="width: 90%; height: 50px">
        <button aria-label="Search" class="wp-block-search__button has-heading-font-family has-icon wp-element-button" type="submit" style="margin-left: 5px">
            <svg class="search-icon" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
                <path d="M13 5c-3.3 0-6 2.7-6 6 0 1.4.5 2.7 1.3 3.7l-3.8 3.8 1.1 1.1 3.8-3.8c1 .8 2.3 1.3 3.7 1.3 3.3 0 6-2.7 6-6S16.3 5 13 5zm0 10.5c-2.5 0-4.5-2-4.5-4.5s2-4.5 4.5-4.5 4.5 2 4.5 4.5-2 4.5-4.5 4.5z" fill="white"></path>
            </svg>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="category-search-check" id="journal-category-check" name="category" value="journal">
        <label for="journal-category-check"> Journal </label>
        <input type="checkbox" class="category-search-check" id="interview-category-check" name="category" value="interview">
        <label for="interview-category-check"> Interview </label>
<input type="checkbox" class="category-search-check" id="short-category-check" name="category" value="short">
        <label for="short-category-check"> Short-form </label>
    </div>
</form>

And this, in functions.php in the child theme, to check parameters:
function get_url_parameters(){
    // Access the URL parameters
    $all = ['journal','interview', 'short'];
    $s = isset($_GET['s']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['s']) : null;
    $category = isset($_GET['category']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['category']) : $all;

    // Check if parameters are set and echo them
    if ($s) {
        echo '<p>Search is: ' . esc_html($s) . '</p>';
    }

    if ($category) {
        echo '<p>Category is: ' . esc_html($category) . '</p>';
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'get_url_parameters' ); 

I am always forcibly redirected to an error page for eg. mywebsite.com/search/?s=xyz, although both of these things technically work. (I switched to the 2021 theme to test and it would stay on the same page only if i entered the parameters manually, but not when submitted through the form). How do I stop wordpress from assuming it is an undefined new page and redirecting to an error page? Several tutorials and forum replies say to write a custom template in php, but I do not seem to be able to include one, at least in the 2024 theme. Is there a way to do this in 2024 theme or would I be better off going back to earlier themes?
(I've used php & similar in learning environments, and this is my first time learning how to get it to work with wordpress).
Thanks!
